# Android studio library

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, groovy, retrofit, android-volley

My team and I just developed a web base system. Next, we are planning to build an android mobile app version of the system. But none of us have experience of creating a mobile app. I did some reading from google, I saw many posting about kotlin, volley, retrofit etc.

One thing  I still don't understand, can someone tell me how kotlin, groovy are different with retrofit and volley?
Is it just like web base development where one is for front end development and another one is for backend?

My app would need to constantly fetch and submit data to phpmyadmin (which I put in my VPS hosting).
Can someone give me a suggestion which library is the best for me to use to create my mobile app?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kotlin is one of the supported languages (and the one Google promotes) for developing native Android apps in Android Studio (Java is the other one). Groovy you'll barely need to touch, it's just used in the build config files that you edit. Volley and Retrofit are just libraries for doing networking stuff like making web requests and talking to API endpoints. If you've never made an app, it might be worth at least reading through something like https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-fundamentals/overview but another option you have is using a `WebView` to act like a "browser"

Comment: Did webview is more advantageous than developing a native apps?

Comment: It's like an embedded browser, so if you already have a web app, you can just display that inside your Android app. There's some work involved in wiring it up, but it's less than rewriting the whole frontend from scratch and learning how to do things through Android. The downside is it's a web app, not a native one - probably doesn't look like an Android app, requires an internet connection to display (unless you bundle some HTML/scripts/etc with the app and make it work locally), general limitations in what it can do compared to a native app that interacts with the system, etc

Comment: Okay I get it. May I ask your opinion for 1 more thing? For an app that constantly need to fetch and submit data to online database, is it advisable to use a framework? Or is it better to just write the code on my own?

Comment: I can't answer that bud, it depends what you're doing and what your needs are! But there are lots of widely used, robust, well-maintained libraries like Retrofit (for example) that make your life easier - definitely make use of that kind of thing, instead of writing your own networking code. Or whatever code - don't reinvent the wheel, don't give yourself more work and more responsibility than you need to, IMO. *Especially* if you're starting out on Android, there's enough to learn without writing/testing/maintaining your own networking library, y'know?

Comment: I mean framework like flutter, react native etc will it make my work easier?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea personally - if you're "fetching and submitting data" then that's easy enough using basic Android and the recommended Jetpack libraries, and typical stuff like Retrofit. There's enough there to give you easy networking and a reactive design. But I personally don't know anything about Flutter or React Native, or your background in web dev and if those frameworks would make things easier and more familiar to you. This isn't a place for recommendations anyway - best thing I could suggest is asking on somewhere like Reddit, or read some tutorials and see what looks promising

Comment: Okay. Thank you for still answering all my question. Have a good day :)